# DateTime.Today.AddHours(11.10) is 11:06 (not 11:10)

Tags: c#, datetime

I have seen posts on how to define a specific time but couldn't find on discrepancy issues. Hope someone can enlighten me.

I want to define a schedule time as let's say 11.10 a.m in windows service. I have my code like this.

```
scheduledDailyRun = DateTime.Today.AddHours(11.10);  // testing
eventLog1.WriteEntry("Scheduled defined @ " + scheduledDailyRun.ToString()); //<<--DEBUG
```

When I check eventlog1, it says "Scheduled defined @ 26/11/2013 11:06:00 AM". Why is it not 11.10 which is defined up there as DateTime.Today.AddHours(11.10)?

Comment: Those darned Babylonians.

Comment: @HansPassant - there should be special version of upvote for "brighten up my day". :)

Answer (score 9):

.10 = 10%

10% of 1 hour (60 minutes) = 6 minutes.

11.06 is correct.

Use `.AddHours(11).AddMinutes(10);` instead

Answer (score 3):

To add 11 hrs 10 min, use following

```
DateTime.Today.AddHours(11).AddMinutes(10);
```